# SFINAE does not properly disable ambiguous overloads

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading, sfinae

I'm trying to build a more flexible version of `std::equal_to`, which can be called on objects of two different types `T1`and `T2` and only requires that `T1::operator==(T2)` *or* `T2::operator==(T1)` is defined. I'm using C++17. First, I have some struct that tests if `SomeType::operator==(OtherType)` is defined:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<class FromT, class ToT, class Dummy = void>
struct EqualityOperatorDefined : std::false_type {};

template<class FromT, class ToT>
struct EqualityOperatorDefined <FromT, ToT, decltype(std::declval<FromT>() == std::declval<ToT>())> 
  : std::true_type {};
```

I think that this works - at least, replacing the usage of `EqualityOperatorDefined` with `true` or `false` in the following does not make the problem go away. The actual flexible `equal_to` is this:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class FlexibleEqualsTo
{
private:
    static constexpr bool cmpT1toT2 = EqualityOperatorDefined<T1, T2>::value;
    static constexpr bool cmpT2toT1 = EqualityOperatorDefined<T2, T1>::value;
public:
    template<class Dummy = T1>
    constexpr bool operator()(const std::enable_if_t<cmpT1toT2, Dummy> & lhs, const T2& rhs)
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }

    template<class Dummy = T1>
    constexpr bool operator()(const std::enable_if_t<cmpT2toT1 && !cmpT1toT2, Dummy> & lhs, const T2& rhs)
    {
        return rhs == lhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    FlexibleEqualsTo<int, int> foo;
}
```

You can find the complete code [here at godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WePfvMva4).

However, GCC and Clang both complain about erroneous overloads here. GCC tells me:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'class FlexibleEqualsTo<int, int>':
<source>:32:32:   required from here
<source>:25:17: error: 'template<class Dummy> constexpr bool FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::operator()(std::enable_if_t<(FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::cmpT2toT1 && (! FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::cmpT1toT2)), Dummy>&, const T2&) [with Dummy = Dummy; T1 = int; T2 = int]' cannot be overloaded with 'template<class Dummy> constexpr bool FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::operator()(std::enable_if_t<FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::cmpT1toT2, Dummy>&, const T2&) [with Dummy = Dummy; T1 = int; T2 = int]'
   25 |  constexpr bool operator()(const std::enable_if_t<cmpT2toT1 && !cmpT1toT2, Dummy> & lhs, const T2& rhs)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
<source>:19:17: note: previous declaration 'template<class Dummy> constexpr bool FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::operator()(std::enable_if_t<FlexibleEqualsTo<T1, T2>::cmpT1toT2, Dummy>&, const T2&) [with Dummy = Dummy; T1 = int; T2 = int]'
   19 |  constexpr bool operator()(const std::enable_if_t<cmpT1toT2, Dummy> & lhs, const T2& rhs)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
```

Only one of the two boolean expressions in `std::enable_if` can be true. Thus, the other (in this case: the second) definition of `operator()` should be SFINAEed away, and there should be no overloading problems.

I think I avoided the usual pitfalls of applying SFINAE. Both function templates depend on their template parameter.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: FYI in C++20 `a == b` can call `decltype(b)::operator==(decltype(a))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SFINAE detector for `operator==` is bugged. Replace this:

```
decltype(std::declval<FromT>() == std::declval<ToT>())
```

with this:

```
decltype(std::declval<FromT>() == std::declval<ToT>(), void())
```

Comment: This actually works! Thanks. Not sure why, though. So I assume that you are using the sequence operator here to force the type of the expression inside `decltype(…)` to always be void, even if `operator==` is not defined. Why is that necessary? Shouldn't template substitution just fail if `operator==` is undefined, and thus the template be removed?

Comment: @LukasBarth No, if `==` is not defined it will fail even with `void()`. Your problem was that the `class Dummy` is `void`, which didn't match your specialization (which expected `Dummy` = `bool`).

Comment: Ah, now I see, thanks. So another solution would have been to change the default for `Dummy` to `bool`, since that is the result of `decltype(std::declval<FromT>() == std::declval<ToT>())`, if the operator is defined. Thanks!

Comment: @LukasBarth Yep.